# What powershell module to import in order to run "Read-ADRecoveryInformation"?

Tags: active-directory, powershell, bitlocker

I tried to run **Read-ADRecoveryInformation** but hit with this infamous error message.
[image]

I tried the following cmdlets to look for the module but I could not find it.

Get-command -Module TrustedPlatformModule

Get-Command -Module Bitlocker

Does anyone know what module I should import in order to allow me to run this cmdlet?

Any feedback would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at :

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/mbam/read-adrecoveryinformation?view=win-mdop2-ps

Underneath the title it says : Module: MBAM

If you click on it referres to :
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/mbam/?view=win-mdop2-ps

I believe this answers your question if not, let me know.